# pass a class as a parameter to class than calling enumValues with the class that passed

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, enums

I am trying to pass a value (class) to another class, and in that class I will use the parameter(the passed class) with `enumValues<parameter>()`

I have tried passing generic `MyClass<T>()`
and than `enumValues<T>()`
but I am getting "cannot use T as a reified , use class instead".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context of where you're using this, you can simply declare the method as inline and reified:

```
inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> useEnumValues() {
  val values = enumValues<T>()
}
```

Otherwise, if you require the class reference:

```
fun <T : Enum<T>> useEnumSet(enumClass: Class<T>) {
  val values = EnumSet.allOf(enumClass)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Class` value is called `cls`, just call [`cls.enumConstants`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()).